# Capture groups are ignored when renaming files

Tags: 12.04, rename, regex

I have a number of files in this format:

```
##.## - File name.mp4
```

I want to rename them to:

```
s##e##.mp4
```

This is what I came up with:

```
rename -n "s/^(\d{2})\.(\d{2}).*/s$1e$2.mp4/"
```

It works when I tested it on http://regexr.com/ but when I run the command on my Ubuntu 12.04 installation all my files get renamed to `se.mp4`

So it looks like the groups are being ignored or not inserted or something along those lines. Am I missing something blindingly obvious or is something else going on?

I ended up using pyRenamer and that worked wonderfully, but I would still like to know why `rename` isn't working properly.

Cheers and thanks for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think perhaps your use of double quotes is allowing the shell to expand `$1` and `$2`

```
$ rename -nv "s/^(\d{2})\.(\d{2}).*/s$1e$2.mp4/" *.mp4
12.34 File name.mp4 renamed as se.mp4
```

whereas with single quotes around the rename expression

```
$ rename -nv 's/^(\d{2})\.(\d{2}).*/s$1e$2.mp4/' *.mp4
12.34 File name.mp4 renamed as s12e34.mp4
```