# Rename using both captured groups and other variables

Tags: bash, rename, regex

In this [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/431128/capture-groups-are-ignored-when-renaming-files) I understood that we can only refer to captured groups in the rename command using single quotes.

Is there a way to use both captured groups and other variables in the same rename command?

Example:

```
var="-old_file"
cd /etc
rename 's/(bash\.bashrc)/$1$var/' *
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either enclose `$1` in single quotes, and `$var` in double quotes:

```
$ rename -n 's/(bash\.bashrc)/$1'"$var"/ *
rename(bash.bashrc, bash.bashrc-old_file)
```

or

```
$ rename -n 's/(bash\.bashrc)/$1'"$var"'/' *
rename(bash.bashrc, bash.bashrc-old_file)
```

or enclose the whole expression in double quotes, and backslash-escape `$1` to prevent it from being expanded by the shell:

```
$ rename -n "s/(bash\.bashrc)/\$1$var/" *
rename(bash.bashrc, bash.bashrc-old_file)
```